# git - get remote file content

Tags: git, gulp

Is there a way in git to get the content of a specific file on the remote repo?

I would like, using gulp, to get the remote package.json version and manipulate the local package.json to match.

The goal is to prevent re-occuring git conflicts on the package.json version field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have fetched data from remote (all you need is to `git fetch`, it will not touch your current working tree) you can then use:

```
git show <ref>:<path>
```

So in your example you can view content of the file via

```
git show origin/master:package.json
```

Comment: I see it processes immediately – looks like it shows local copy of remote content from .git folder internals. Is there any way to actually fetch it from the remote without doing the `git fetch`?

Comment: As far as I know - no.